# Use one form field for two Model entries in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am making a link aggregator where people can submit articles.

My data model contains

```
Article
    title Text
    url Text
    domain Text
```

I would like the user to input a url into the form and then I run a function on the URL to extract the domain and then save both in the database.
I would like the user to only have to enter the URL once, as in:

```
entryForm = renderDivs $ Article¬
     <$> areq   textField "Url" Nothing¬
     <*> areq   textField "Title" Nothing¬
```

But I get this error

```
Couldn't match type ‘Text -> Article’ with ‘Article’
  Expected type: Form Article
    Actual type: blaze-markup-0.7.0.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup
               -> MForm
                    (HandlerT App IO)
                    (FormResult (Text -> Article),
                     WidgetT (HandlerSite (HandlerT App IO)) IO ())
In the expression:
  renderDivs
  $ Article <$> areq textField "Url" Nothing
    <*> areq textField "Title" Nothing
In an equation for ‘entryForm’:
    entryForm
      = renderDivs
        $ Article <$> areq textField "Url" Nothing
          <*> areq textField "Title" Nothing
```

because clearly the form doesn't match the type Article.

I am not sure how to proceed. I've been told I can either a)write an alternative Article' datatype and convert between the two, or b) create my own custom field, though both of those seem difficult to me as a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a helper function like:

```
makeArticle :: Text -> Text -> Article
```

Which takes the title and URL, extracts the domain name from the URL, and constructs an `Article` value. Then you can use that in place of calling the `Article` data constructor directly.